# Calculating Percentile in Python Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, percentile

I'm trying to calculate the percentile of each number within a dataframe and add it to a new column called 'percentile'.

This is my attempt:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats

data = {'symbol':'FB','date':['2012-05-18','2012-05-21','2012-05-22','2012-05-23'],'close':[38.23,34.03,31.00,32.00]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

close = df['close']

for i in df:
    df['percentile'] = stats.percentileofscore(close,df['close'])
```

The column is not being filled and results in 'NaN'. This should be fairly easy, but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: no need for looping through `for i in df`. see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44607827/1870832

Comment: You should know broadcast in Pandas. see this [broadcast](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29955358/5496463).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
df.close.apply(lambda x: stats.percentileofscore(df.close.sort_values(),x))
```

or

```
df.close.rank(pct=True)
```

Output:

```
0    1.00
1    0.75
2    0.25
3    0.50
Name: close, dtype: float64
```

Comment: very simple answer, thanks @scott-boston

Comment: Use `.rank` -- should be significantly faster

Comment: `.rank` is 100% what you should use. That lambda function while correct will be MUCH slower